# Add member to google groups using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-groups-api

I am looking for a method to add an user to my own google-group (at least to send him an invitation) from google apps script.

The snippet is:

```
  var options = {  "method"  : "POST",
        "payload" : {"email": email,"role": "MEMBER"},   
        "muteHttpExceptions": true};

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/" + respGroup+"/members?key=" + key, options);
```

But the response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [{
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "required",
      "message": "Login Required",
      "locationType": "header",
      "location": "Authorization"
    }],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
  }
}
```

I understood that the problem could be the OAuth authentication, but how do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that easily using the AdminDirectory API (extended Google services that should be activated in the ressource tab)
[image]

The code is as simple as this :

```
function addGroupMember(userEmail,groupEmail) {
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: "MEMBER"
  };
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log("User %s added as a member of group %s.", userEmail, groupEmail);
}
```

Comment: thank you. Now the returned error is "Resource Not Found: groupKey" either if I use the groupEmail or groupId.

Comment: I use it in an education account, I'll have to test if it works on my regular account as well.  I'll keep you informed. Did you authorize the API completely (in both links) ?

Comment: yeah I did it. But somewhere I read that you should use Google group for business, which means you have your domain. Could you confirm??

Comment: @Sergeinsas This only works if you have a Google group business account?

Comment: Business or education, not on regular Gmail account.